# ParameterExpression to Object Casting with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to cast any object from `ParameterExpression` class.

This is sample code (and pseudo what i want to say) :

```
public void Execute(Expression<Action<TService>> operation)
{
    try
    {

        var param = operation.Parameters[0]; //myparameter to cast
        var obj = param as AnyCastObject; // I want to cast
        DoSomething(obj); // and do something this object without losing any assigned propery.

        operation.Compile().Invoke(OpenNewChannel);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseChannel();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This is my method body:

`Execute(x => x.UserAuthentication(requestDto));`

I want to manipulate requestDto.

Comment: You don't seem to comprehend how expressions work. `param` isn't the "value" of the parameter, it is a "parameter" in the sense "the descriptor of the parameter". "casting" the "descriptor of the parameter" doesn't have any sense. What you can do is create a new expression tree where the "value" of the parameter is casted to something else and then something is done.

Comment: I know param is not a value. I write this sample for pseudo that what i want yo say. But i dont understand what your saying.

Comment: So what do you want to cast? Do you want to have a "new" `ParameterExpression` for a different type (`MyService` instead of `TService`)? Do you want to change the parameter type of the operation from `TService` to `MyService`? Or what?

Comment: And when you `operation.Compile()`, do you want to compile the `operation` that was passed or do you want to compile an `operation` that you modified in some way?

Comment: In fact i want to copy or extract parameter before invoking. İf i want to create new instance of parameter then i use Activator.CreateInstance. But i dont want New instance i want to reference current instance parameter which passing to expression.

Comment: thats I'm calling function `var response = Execute(x => x.UserAuthentication(requestDto));` I want to manipulate request DTO.

Comment: Ok... it should be what you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is... With this you should be able to extract your `requestDto`.

Note that you don't need the `Invoke()` when you call compiled expressions.

```
operation.Compile()(OpenNewChannel);
```

is enough.

Now, to extract the `requestDto`:

```
// Works for Execute(x => x.UserAuthentication(something))
// where something must be a constant value, a variable,
// a field, a property
var param = operation.Parameters[0]; //myparameter to cast

var body = operation.Body as MethodCallExpression;

if (body == null || body.Object != param || body.Method.Name != "UserAuthentication")
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

// If you have a type for the parameter, replace it here:
// object -> yourtype
object requestValue;

var constantExpression = body.Arguments[0] as ConstantExpression;

if (constantExpression == null)
{
    // For nearly all the types of expression, the only way
    // to extract the final value is to compile them and then
    // execute them (the execution is the last "()" )

    // If you have a type for the parameter, replace it here:
    // Func<object> -> Func<yourtype>
    requestValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(body.Arguments[0]).Compile()();
}
else
{
    // Constant expression values can be directly extracted

    // If you have a type for the parameter, replace it here:
    // (yourtype)constantExpression.Value
    requestValue = constantExpression.Value;
}
```